# Why can LayoutBuilder not have an intrinsic dimensions?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the docs of `_RenderLayoutBuilder` in `layout_builder.dart` it says:

```
'LayoutBuilder does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.\n'
'Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require running the layout '
'callback speculatively, which might mutate the live render object tree.'
```

What is the “layout callback” in this case, and why would it have to be called speculatively?

I am trying to wrap my head around how to implement a custom `RenderBox` that similarly to `LayoutBuilder` builds its child using a builder callback and supports intrinsic dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

The "layout callback" is the `builder` function you pass to the LayoutBuilder.

Calculating the intrinsic dimensions of any RenderObject involves a speculative layout pass.  LayoutBuilder builds its widget subtree at layout time, which can mutate the render object tree if its contraints have changed.  Since this speculative layout pass almost certainly uses different constraints than what will ultimately be used in the layout, it is impossible for LayoutBuilder to work the way you want.

This is fundamental to how LayoutBuilder works, so I doubt you'd be able to modify it to support intrinsic dimensions.  Depending on what layout changes you plan to support, you might consider basing this custom RenderBox on `CustomMultiChildLayout` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation. This helps me. It would be great if you could clarify in more detail why the calculation of intrinsic dimensions is always a speculative layout pass? Why am I speculating? For me, it seems like a simple calculation. I plan to have a render box with three children. I want to wrap one in a media query context with padding based on the height of the other two.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to wrap widget with `Column` and set `mainAxisSize`: `MainAxisSize.min`, so that high `arlertDialog` changes according to its intrinsic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you face such type of problem always use wrap AlertDialog with StatefulBuilder like image then problem solved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m3hq.png)

Comment: I suggest you to include the code directly in your post (using code blocks) instead of redirecting to a capture of your editor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).